# Playwright can't access "page" for new interface

Tags: typescript, command-line-interface, playwright

I am trying to create baseClass and inherit all common system declarations from it.
I am not able to provide "this.page" inside the new interface.
I am receiving error :

> Property 'page' is used before its initialization.ts(2729)
> baseClass.ts(16, 3): 'page' is declared here.

My code:

```
// Import Playwright test library.
import { Page } from "@playwright/test";
import { tsMethods } from "../custom-methods/other-methods/tsMethods";

// Declare a class.
export class baseClass {
  // Declare a page varible.
  page: Page;
  // Declare a constructor.
  constructor(page: Page) {
    // Get access to the page property.
    this.page = page;
  }

  public readonly ts = new tsMethods(this.page);

  public async beforeTest() {}
}

// Export the current class.
export default baseClass;
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

```
// Import Playwright test library.
import { Page } from "@playwright/test";
import { tsMethods } from "../custom-methods/other-methods/tsMethods";

// Declare a class.
export class BaseClass {
  // Declare a page constructor.
  constructor(public page: Page){} 

  public readonly ts = new tsMethods(this.page);

  public async beforeTest() {

  }
}

// Export the current class.
export default BaseClass;
```